# R Vector syntax in Python / Pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas

I've created the following code in R.

```
data=c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width")
  terms<- paste(data, collapse='+')
```

and this gives;

```
"Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width"
```

Is there a way of doing something similar in Python / Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use join:

```
d = ["Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"]
x = '+'.join(d)
print(x)
```

output:

```
Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width
```